# Best algorithm for Renyi–Ulam Game with lies

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

Player $A$ thinks of number between 1 and $n$ and ask $B$ to guess the number with minimum number of decision queries (yes or no type).

**Game** :

1. $A$ chooses an element in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.
2. $B$ tries to guess this number by asking Yes/No
   questions.

Binary search is a way to solve the problem, so $\log n$ many queries will be sufficient to solve the problem when player $A$ does not lie. If player $A$ lies exactly once then we can problem with $2\log n$ many queries (by just asking the same query two times). What if $A$ may lie many times, but with a rule that they may not lie twice in a row and should say the truth when we find their number?

I was thinking of this and I found a [relevant paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0407504.pdf) which was hard for me to understand. Could anyone give a simpler version of the algorithm when $A$ can't lie twice in a row and says the truth when their number has been guessed?

Comment: You did not specify exactly what queries we can use. To apply binary search we need to be able to ask whether $x\ge k$ for some $k\in[n]$.

Comment: I'm not sure your variant appears in the literature. It certainly doesn't appear in the linked paper. It is known that without the rule about "finding the number", the game becomes impossible to solve. The usual strategy shows that it is impossible to know whether 0 or 1 is the correct answer. In your model this is trivially solvable.

Comment: Agree with Ariel's ocmment: can you clarify what is an allowed query?

Comment: @Ariel the type of query which we can ask is of binary search one

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Could you be more specific please

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It is a simpler case  of what is given in literature and i am trying to build an AI to play the game

Comment: The paper you link to addresses the problem of finitely many lies. You are asking a completely different question. If you are only promised that there are no two lies in a row, then it is provably impossible to find the unknown element. In your case, there is an obvious solution using $n-1$ queries of the form "is the unknown element $i$", but it's not clear that you even allow these queries (since they're not of the binary search type, i.e. not of the form "is the unknown element at most $i$").

Comment: Please [edit] your post to (1) specify what kind of query is allowed (only queries asking "is the number $\le c$?" for some $c$; or can we ask queries "is the number $\in S$?" for some set $S$?), and (2) what precisely you mean by "say the truth when we find their number" (does this only apply to queries "is the number $=c$?" for some $c$, or does it also apply to any other queries as well?).